# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Tags: php, json

Declared php variable like below.

```
$data = {
            "parameters": {
            "o.product": "sam",
            "o.model": "121",
            "o.BaseModel": "4444"
            }
        };
```

it showing unexpected {.

Comment: Whats this? PHP is not Javascript.

Comment: @tkausl didnt get you

Comment: JSON is a string format and needs to be enclosed in quotes. Try `$data = '{ "parameters": { "o.product": "sam",  "o.model": "121",  "o.BaseModel": "4444"  } }';`